# JSON response with Jersey is not working

Tags: java, json, maven, jersey

I'm developing a Web Service with Jersey, I'm having problems because when I return the JSON response to the browser I get this error message:

**A message body writer for Java class org.json.JSONObject, and Java type class org.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/json was not found.**

This is what I coded:

```
 @Path("details")
  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  public Response questionDetails (){
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
      json.put("kind", "Yes/No");
      json.put("tipeCode", 1);
      return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
  }
```

On the same java class I have a working example from another website:

```
@Path("test")
      @GET
      @Produces("application/json")
      public Response convertFtoCfromInput() throws JSONException, SQLException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        float celsius;
        celsius =  (f - 32)*5/9; 
        jsonObject.put("F Value", f); 
        jsonObject.put("C Value", celsius); 
        jsonObject.put("number", number);
        jsonObject.put("statement", statement); 

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nJSON from Path: \n\n" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
      }
```

The two peaces of code are very similar each to each other, but I don't understand why mi part isn't working. I just want to return the JSON, like in the example but without the String.

Thanks

Comment: Testing with the piece of code that is working I noticed that if I just return the JSON object without the String I'm having the same error, then, how can I return the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I solved! I was very stuck so I didn't see how much easy is the solution I just had to transform JSON to String:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(json.toString()).build();
```

With this is everything solved. I'm very embarrassed.